# What is the difference between pg_tileserv and Martin?

Tags: postgis, vector-tiles

I'm looking for a way to display vector data in PostGIS on a map. Initially I was going to setup a GeoServer to do this via WMS, but have since seen that PostGIS allows for creating vector tiles directly, which seems a little nicer. I came across [CrunchyData/pg_tileserv](https://github.com/CrunchyData/pg_tileserv) via the [crunchydata blog](https://www.crunchydata.com/blog). This is included in the documentation for `pg_tileserv`:

> In a sincere act of flattery, the API looks a lot like that of the Martin tile server

So I then went and looked at the [maplibre/martin](https://github.com/maplibre/martin) project.

These projects look directly comparable to me, since they both convert HTTP requests to PostGIS queries and return tiles. What are the differences between them? I see this gis.stackexchange post - https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/389707/82513, saying that `Martin` and `pg_tileserv` are roughly equivalent. But that still doesn't answer the question as to why create two separate projects.

Comment: Difference: language, maturity, development cycles - developers, umbrella organizations. Reason: maybe Go fits better into your tech stack and skill set than Rust?

Comment: All good reasons. I'm looking at these pieces of software strictly from a usage perspective at the moment. So in other words they are directly comparable - thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- [pg_tileserve](https://github.com/CrunchyData/pg_tileserv) is a Go-based tile server that focuses on generating tiles from a single Postgres database server.
- [Martin](https://github.com/maplibre/martin) is a Rust-based tile server that supports multiple simultaneous Postgres databases as well as serving from MBTiles and PMTiles files. Martin can combine vector tiles as layers from all those sources.

Features available in both: auto-discover for PostgreSQL tables and functions that return tiles. Extensive configuration system.

Disclaimer: I have been maintaining and adding new features to Martin.

Comment: Thank you - that is very helpful and motivation to test Martin.